# Ubuntu 20.04.2 removable media (cd/dvd) and usb drives no longer auto mounting

Tags: snap, systemd, vlc, automount, udev

Worked fine until about a month ago when noticed inserting a CD or DVD wouldn't bring up the default player application. Start the player manually and the (internal sata) drive has no problem accessing the media.

Try inserting a disc formatted with data, the partition is not mounted and (default app) caja is not launched.  Can mount the disc manually and then access it, but the automount is  not working.

Same thing happens when plugging-in a usb thumbdrive or usb-connected harddrive. syslog will show the usb storage device is detected properly but the udev system is failing to mount the filesystem.  Can successfully manually mount and access the filesystem so the device is recognized and accessible, just not being automounted by udev.

I'm totally clueless re:the leviathan udev/systemd and how the magic there happens and don't even know where to start.  Have fundamentally changed nothing on the system after install other than regular updates via apt update and apt dist-upgrade from the ubuntu repositories.

Running an additional couple of 20.04.2 boxes that aren't showing this problem so can't say why my daily driver has become so recalcitrant in regards to the auto-mount thing.  A small annoyance, but would like to nail it down if possible.

Any ideas where to start??

Answer (score 0):

Turns out installing the 'snap' version of vlc somehow broke the mounting behaviour of systemd-udevd.  Fixing was as simple as removing the vlc 'snap' package, re-installing the vlc 'snap', followed by a re-boot.

Don't ask me.  "worked for me" as is said.   ¯_(ツ)_/¯